# Can't deregister / dequeue scripts in WordPress

Tags: footer

There's a plugin putting scripts in the footer of my site seemingly with the rest of the enqueued scripts that have been enqueued with wp_enqueue_script( $in_footer = true ). However when I use the following code, these scripts are not present.

var_dump(wp_scripts());

I know the handles for these scripts (without the -js at the end) and have tried deregistering and dequeuing these scripts with priorities from 0 to 99999999999. The code at the moment is:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_unused_homepage_code' , 99999999999 );
function remove_unused_homepage_code() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'handle_here' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'handle_here' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'handle_here' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'handle_here' );
}
```

I've looked at the plugin's enqueue functions and they're just normal wp_enqueue_script() functions with no priorities defined.

How in the world do I get rid of these scripts? The plugin, which is https://wpdatatables.com/ btw, wants to put these huge scripts on all pages of my site regardless of where the plugin is used.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are dequeuing before the script may even be enqueued. Test with a hook that is actioned after wp_enqueue_scripts to deque.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/

```
/**
 * Dequeue the jQuery UI script.
 *
 * Hooked to the wp_print_scripts action, with a late priority (100),
 * so that it is after the script was enqueued.
 */
function wpdocs_dequeue_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 100 );
```

Comment: I think the premise is correct - but the `wp_print_scripts` hook is in many cases still too early to adjust scripts enqueued for the footer (as it executes when the header scripts are printed). Consider using the `wp_footer` action with a near-zero priority instead in order to account for any scripts enqueued by logic executed after the header has printed.